# Managed Package - Increase field length

Tags: managed-package, update

I have a field in my managed package, which is currently declared as Currency(10,2). I would like to increase the decimal places for this field. Though Salesforce allows to do this, I would like to know if this will impact the field's value in my scbscriber orgs.

Could you please guide me & provide links to documentations if you know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

yes this will impact end user and client's org.

For example if my invoice was of 99.99$ then it may start appearing as 99.9876

Comment: For new data only, correct? For existing data, a value of $99.99 will appear as €99.9900 when the field is changed to 10,4.

Comment: No, SFDC store many decimal points and show only 2 as you configured. So it will show 99.9876 for **OLD** values too. Test this properly. i had burned my hands.